# Adding multiple filters to graphql-ruby implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql, json-api, graphql-ruby

I'd like to add filtering and sorting to my GraphQL types (using [graphql-ruby](https://graphql-ruby.org/) gem).
I've been looking for existing solutions for that and the only reasonable option I've found is creating a custom resolver.
The problem with this approach is that I "lose" Active Record capabilities like using custom methods on the models for filtering or field resolution.
Has anyone come across a decent (and existing) solution for this?

It's worth mentioning [graphiti](https://www.graphiti.dev/) which offers these out-of-the-box but diverts from the GraphQL spec and uses JSON:API instead. It's great but I'd like to benefit from GraphQL subscriptions and built-in authorization.

Answer (score 0):

There are some gotchas with respect to having a generalised solution for sorting and filtering and the GraphQL standard. It's hard to define a concrete schema for a set of arguments that could easily apply to different types well. Because you might naturally have something like `sort: Enum[name_asc, name_desc, country_asc, country_desc]`.

If you are happy with that limitation, and willing to receive your params as some kind of generalised `sort: String` and write code to ensure what is sent is a valid value. Then you can use a `Connection` (https://graphql-ruby.org/pagination/using_connections) for this purpose.